# AutoHotKey - Three finger dragging script causing minor issue, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

### Background

I have the following AHK script (obtained from https://medium.com/@dakshin.k1/enable-3-finger-gesture-for-click-and-drag-on-windows-and-linux-cd7165b66851):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance force

; Enable three-finger drag
drag_enabled := 0

+^#F22::
    if (drag_enabled) {
        Click up
        drag_enabled := 0
    } else {
        drag_enabled := 1
        Click down
    }
    return

LButton::
    if (drag_enabled) {
        Click up
        drag_enabled := 0
    } else {
        click
    }
    return
```

This is supposed to enable Mac-style three-finger dragging on *any* Windows 10 laptop's touchpad, but with the following three steps required:

1. Perform a three-finger tap.
2. Move the mouse pointer to wherever you'd like. If dragging a window, the window should (and does) follow the cursor as you move it. If selecting text, you should see the text being highlighted like you'd expect and even two-finger scrolling should work (and does)!
3. Perform a single-finger tap to complete the simulated gesture.

### The problem

I am absolutely gobsmacked that AHK is capable of all of this, so it doesn't come as a surprise that it doesn't *quite* work as well as I'd hoped. After an indeterminable amount of time, **I can no longer click/tap with my touchpad normally**.

### My questions

1. What does `+^#F22` *actually do*? The docs and my limited knowledge of AHK seem to imply that it would set up `Shift+Ctrl+Win+Whatever F22 means` as a hotkey that enables step 1. above. But does it also enable step 2? If not...
2. How is AHK able to track the mouse pointer, keeping the drag action going while any amount of finger removals from, and re-contacts with, the touchpad are possible? **What Win32 API functions are being called by which lines of the script?**
3. How can I fix the touchpad clicking problem (I have a feeling that the answer is "you can't", but please prove me wrong)?

I have spent about 2 hours on this already, reading the docs and trying to refamiliarise myself with AHK in general, because it's been an age since I last used it (and even then, I never did anything *half* as advanced as this)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+^#F22` does what you said, it registers a hotkey for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F22</kbd> (yes, F keys 13-24 exist).
So on your installation, performing a three-finger-tap should send that key combination to Windows.
You can try that with e.g `SendInput, +^#{F22}`
That should open up the Windows search/Cortana.

On my laptop a three-finger-tap sent just a simple <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to Windows.
But I guess on your installation it's different (for whatever reason).
You can find out what exactly gets sent by using e.g. `Keyhistory`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyHistory.htm)</sup>.

---

So anyway, how does the script work? It's actually really really simple and clearly made by an AHK novice.
When a three-finger-tap is intercepted (via the `+^#F22` hotkey), the scripts check if the user defined toggle `drag_enabled` evaluates to true or false.

- If false, dragging is not in progress. So it starts dragging by sending a LButton down event.
- If true, dragging is in progress. So it ends the dragging by sending a LButton up event.

The `LButton` hotkey is there so the dragging can also be ended by clicking LButton.
The hotkey is actually badly implemented though, and it breaks the native functionality of LButton. I'll fix that below.

---

*How is AHK able to track the mouse pointer, keeping the drag action going while any amount of finger removals from, and re-contacts with, the touchpad are possible?*

AHK doesn't care about any of that. It's all handled by Windows. Doing which ever mouse movements (except clicking) don't matter for the dragging action. Only clicking would cancel LButton being held down.

---

*How can I fix the touchpad clicking problem (I have a feeling that the answer is "you can't", but please prove me wrong)?*

I don't really know what you mean, but I could guess/hope it's just caused by the badly implemented `LButton` hotkey. I guess try and see if my improved version below fixes it.

---

So the improved version:

```
+^#F22::
    if (drag_enabled) 
        Click, Up
    else
        Click, Down
    drag_enabled := !drag_enabled
return

#If, drag_enabled
LButton::
    Click, Up
    drag_enabled := false
return
#If
```

Changes are basically just compacting/removing useless code and properly implementing the `LButton` hotkey to not break the native functionality of LButton when dragging is not in progress.
Seems to work just fine on my laptop, except I replace `+^#F22` with `#s`.

Comment: *On my laptop a three-finger-tap sent just a simple `Win+S` to Windows* - you are correct, that is the default action registered within Win 10, and worked for me before I set any of this up. I figured out most of the rest of what you said on my own just by reading the script, but was mainly just confused about how `+^#F22` works. Meh, for whatever reason, it does, so TYVM for your answer. I'll test your improved script extensively and LYK if it works ;-)

Comment: It indeed seems as though the problem with the initial script was the `LButton` hotkey definition at the bottom. Thanks so much for your help! :D I still don't understand why the other weird key combination works, nor why <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *doesn't* work for me in *any* AHK script - Windows insists on reserving that hotkey for Windows Search, maybe because I have Cortana disabled...? But anyway, problem solved :D